# Xamarin.iOS Bindings throws "Error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol"

Tags: ios, binding, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I created a xamarin.iOS binding from native static library.

While I am using the binding(.dll file) I get many linker error for duplicate symbols

By looking at the error I observe that the error is related to "Reachability" Class, Reachability is present in the building and hence it is throwing an error.

```
MTOUCH: Error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_OBJC_IVAR_$_BSTemplateViewController._internetReachability'. (MT5212)
```

Do we have to change the native static library or is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: It looks similar to this bug https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=34186 What version of Xamarin.iOS are you using? Could you try updating it latest

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally I got the answer!!

Just I have to add "--registrar:static" to **additional mtouch arguments:** in iOS Build

Note:The source of the answer is [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/10315/native-linking-failed-duplicate-symbols-how-to-solve)

Comment: Solved my problem with Firebase library, big thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to do both your debug and release. I got confused when my error returned and I'd switched build type.

Comment: Regarding to this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/internals/registrar#selecting-a-registrar `--registrar:static` is nowadays the default setting. Also it did not help me with error MT5212. To solve it I had to remove the method from the `ApiDefinitions.cs` which caused the duplicated symbol error. Fortunately, I do not need the method I removed.

Comment: Solved my problem